# Why did my nemo scripts disappeared?

Tags: updates, scripts, nemo

If you are using the Nemo file manager from the "WebUpD8" PPA (https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo) you might have noticed that you cannot launch your custom scripts any more. The right click doesn't show the "Scripts" entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the PPA has been recently updated (2015-05-29) and the path where Nemo looks for scripts has changed.

Your old scripts were located in:

```
~/.gnome2/nemo-scripts/
```

Newer versions of Nemo look into:

```
~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/
```

Just copy your old scripts into the new directory and the scripts will be available again:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/ &&\
cp -r ~/.gnome2/nemo-scripts/* ~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/ &&\
chmod -R +x ~/.local/share/nemo/scripts/*
```

[image]

Note that you might need to restart Nemo for the scripts to appear, just use `nemo -q` in a terminal.